# Уменьшение размера Android приложения

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Как при разработке под Android добиться минимального размера, готового, приложения?

> Увлекся изучением java и дроидом. Попытался сделать "локатор" с помощью Google 
> Maps Android API v2. Полученный apk весит 657 кб, установленное приложение 1.87 мб.
> (100 строк кода, никаких картинок, ничего лишнего). Тот же "Антивирусов Dr.Web 
> Light" - весит 2.24 мб.

Как добиться, что бы готовое приложение занимало как можно меньше места без потери в быстродействии и функциональности?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать ProGuard. Он вырезает все неиспользуемые функции.
Так же можно отказаться от использования библиотек.